# Using APLEdit to create a function in gnu-apl

Tags: function, apl

I'm trying to learn APL from the excellent APL Wiki and gnu-apl on my Mac, but I'm having trouble with creating functions.

Specifically, I'm trying to create the "TRY1" function from the [wiki](http://aplwiki.com/LearnApl/AplFunctions).

It's not working in gnu-apl, so I downloaded and installed [APLEditor](https://github.com/blakemcbride/APLEditor) as per the instructions, and can now invoke the editor in my workspace with:

```
E∆Edit ''
```

I'm a little confused: How can I name and save the function for use in my workspace?

Answer (score 2):

Just to get started with APL, I would use the built-in del (∇) editor, despite the wiki's claim that you probably never need to learn it.  The del editor is the spiritual equivalent of the old EDLIN editor which came with PC-DOS, primitive and painful to use compared to a slick full screen editor.  (It's also all we had in the old days).  Just type in the function exactly as you see it.

∇TRY1

[1]   'Type some numbers: '

[2]   NUM ← ⎕

[3]   'Total is: '(+/NUM)

[4]   ∇

The bracketed line numbers ([1], [2], [3], and [4]) should be supplied by the system, just like a shell prompt.  The final del (∇) after [4] should get you out of edit mode and back into immediate execution mode.

When done, type )FNS and you should see TRY1.  Then type TRY1 to run it.

Afterwards, you can try some of the excellent "aftermarket" editors.

Comment: I'd still like to learn to use APLEdit, but I was also unclear on how to edit and manipulate lines in DEL - this tutorial from MicroAPL cleared up a lot of questions: http://www.microapl.co.uk/apl_help/ch_020_020_940.htm

Comment: That looks like a good tutorial.  As always, amongst the various APL systems, there are always the little differences, in the del editor, full screen editors, and everything else.